# R: read_excel reads dates as numbers

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, date, dplyr

I am importing an excel file from the *Robert Koch Institute* into R using `readxl::read_excel`. However, I am experiencing problems with a row that contains only dates. The date format is *DD.MM.YYYY*, but in the resulting data frame, they appear as seemingly arbitrary numeric values. Here is the code that I am using:

```r
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("path/to/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab_Archiv.xlsx", 
                                        sheet = "BL_7-Tage-Fallzahlen (fixiert)")
head(df)
```

which returns the following output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 494
  `Fallzahlen in d~  ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9 ...10 ...11 ...12 ...13 ...14 ...15
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 NA                   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 NA                   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 NA                   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 NA                43957 43958 43959 43960 43961 43962 43963 43964 43965 43966 43967 43968 43969 43970
5 Baden-Württemberg   908   779   665   706   772   760   774   744   765   725   622   551   549   483
6 Bayern             1318  1246  1182  1223  1148  1151  1198  1194  1115  1022  1022   997   982   921
# ... with 479 more variables: ...16 <dbl>, ...
```

In row number 4, you can see the dates that are clearly not imported correctly. I already tried `col_types="text"` and `col_types="list"`, as this suggested in other posts, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

The excel file can be downloaded in the "Archiv" section of [RKI's webpage](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Inzidenz-Tabellen.html) and this should be the direct [download link](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab_Archiv.xlsx?__blob=publicationFile).

Comment: Note that in Excel, dates are actually just numbers.

Comment: Those look just like the serial numbers excel uses to code the dates, then they can be formatted into many formats. Note how they are sequential...

Comment: Please google "excel dates in r"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the data frame after loading it into R

```
# load data, replace ... with path and file
# dat <- read_xlsx(..., sheet="BL_7-Tage-Fallzahlen (fixiert)")
# get the dates
dates <- as.numeric(dat[4,])

# filter top rows with NAs
dat <- dat[5:nrow(dat),]

# put the dates as column names
colnames(dat)[-1] <- as.character(as.Date(dates[-1], origin="1899-12-30"))

head(dat)
# A tibble: 6 × 494
  `Fallzahlen in den letzte… `2020-05-06` `2020-05-07` `2020-05-08` `2020-05-09`
  <chr>                             <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Baden-Württemberg                   908          779          665          706
2 Bayern                             1318         1246         1182         1223
3 Berlin                              276          265          272          280
4 Brandenburg                         125          116          117          131
5 Bremen                              119          126          140          155
6 Hamburg                              95           85           86           89
# … with 489 more variables: 2020-05-10 <dbl>, 2020-05-11 <dbl>,
#   2020-05-12 <dbl>, 2020-05-13 <dbl>, 2020-05-14 <dbl>, 2020-05-15 <dbl>,
#   2020-05-16 <dbl>, 2020-05-17 <dbl>, 2020-05-18 <dbl>, 2020-05-19 <dbl>,
#   2020-05-20 <dbl>, 2020-05-21 <dbl>, 2020-05-22 <dbl>, 2020-05-23 <dbl>,
#   2020-05-24 <dbl>, 2020-05-25 <dbl>, 2020-05-26 <dbl>, 2020-05-27 <dbl>,
#   2020-05-28 <dbl>, 2020-05-29 <dbl>, 2020-05-30 <dbl>, 2020-05-31 <dbl>,
#   2020-06-01 <dbl>, 2020-06-02 <dbl>, 2020-06-03 <dbl>, 2020-06-04 <dbl>, …
```

Comment: Thank you!! The `origin="1899-12-30"` saved me.